# Cancellation not propagated

Tags: swift, cancellation, swift-concurrency

Cancellation is not propagated through the service class here

```swift
let task = Task<Service.Resource, Error> {
    if Task.isCancelled {
        throw URLError(.cancelled)
    }
    return try await service.loadResource()
}
```

What modification is required on this function to propagate cancellation?

```swift
func loadResource() async throws -> Resource {
    let data = try await load()
    return try decoder.decode(Resource.self, from: data)
}
```

Comment: What do you intend by "propagated" here? What do you expect to happen that does not happen? How does `load()` check for cancellation? (All "cancellation" means is that `Task.isCancelled` is set to `true` for the task and its children. That's all that it does.)

Comment: It’s the children part I need to clarify. URLSession is involved here and I reattempt any recoverable errors with exponential backoff.

Comment: I don't see URLSession anywhere in the above code. You'll need to explain how `load()` is implemented. There's no magic here. Calling `cancel` just sets `Task.isCancelled` in a "task local" way (it's not actually implemented using the task local system, but it behaves similarly). Tasks must check `.isCanceled`. How this interacts with URLSession completely depends on how you use URLSession. Build an mcve. See if it behaves as you expect. If not, then ask the question based on it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within structured concurrency, if you cancel a `Task`, its children will be canceled, too. If you are not seeing the children canceled, one of the following is a likely culprit:

- perhaps the `load` method has introduced additional unstructured concurrency (i.e., another `Task` object was introduced inside `load` method);
- perhaps the `load` method is not using a cancelable `async` method;
- perhaps the attempt to call `cancel` of the `task` variable was done incorrectly … we would need to see the lifecycle of this `task` variable and where you called `cancel` method on its `Task` object.

But, bottom line, you enjoy cancelation propagation if (a) you remain with structured concurrency inside your `Task`; (b) you `await` a method that supports cancelation.

---

As an aside, consider the following:

```swift
let task = Task<Service.Resource, Error> {
    if Task.isCancelled {
        throw URLError(.cancelled)
    }
    return try await service.loadResource()
}
```

That can be simplified to:

```swift
let task = Task<Service.Resource, Error> {
    try Task.checkCancellation()
    return try await service.loadResource()
}
```

Unfortunately, this will be of limited utility. If the the task is canceled after it has started (and because of actor-reentrancy, this is likely), you are probably past this test, awaiting the `loadResource` (which is likely awaiting `load`). What is more important is that `loadResource` (and the `load` method that it calls) must both support cancelation.

People will commonly encourage others to check `if Task.isCancelled {…}` or call `try Task.checkCancellation()`. But more importantly, make sure that `load` supports cancelation. E.g., if you are calling the `async` methods of `URLSession`, such as [`data(for:delegate:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767352-data) or [`data(from:delegate:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767353-data), they support cancelation already.

But if you are using some other other API that predates Swift concurrency (perhaps something wrapped in a `withCheckedContinuation` or `withUnsafeContinuation`), then you would often wrap that in a [`withTaskCancellationHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withtaskcancellationhandler(operation:oncancel:)/), taking advantage of whatever cancelation support that underlying API provides.

But again, it is hard to advise further without seeing the implementation of the `load` method (and how you are canceling this top-level `task`).